# Display arbitrary controls on a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm developing a WPF wizard WiX custom managed bootstrapper application.

Some elements of the wizard are common (for example, the product information and logo at the top), and I don't want to have to redefine these. I also don't want to have to redevelop the whole thing from scratch for each install (yes, there are a number of installs I want to use this with and they have different wizards).

I have a model like this (simplified to avoid confusion)

```
public class WizardModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private UserControl _currentPage;
  public UserControl CurrentPage 
  { 
    get { return _currentPage; }
    set 
    { 
      _currentPage = value;
      if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, "CurrentPage");
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to bind a control so that the control in CurrentPage is displayed when the property changes.

I did experiment with using ContentCrontol but I quickly dismissed that as not intended for this purpose, and I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a few guesses here because there's not a lot of detail in the original question, but I think I get the idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Seems like you would want to have a base class with all of the common controls on it already.  Say we call this class WizardUserControl.  Anyway, let's say we define a Grid inside the WizardUserControl (let's call it CustomGridArea) and that grid will be the main area where we can drop all of our custom controls based on which page of the wizard we are processing.  So maybe WizardUserControl may implement a method like:

```
public class WizardUserControl : UserControl
{
   ...
   // All your standard wizard code stuff/behavior/business logic/etc...
   ...
   ...

   public void InsertCustomizedControl(UserControl customizedControl)
   {
      CustomGridArea.Children.Clear();
      CustomGridArea.Children.Add(customizedControl);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sort of. In any case, the `.Children.Clear` followed by `.Add` seems to have done the trick